# Azure HDI cluster create: how to specify head/worker node type from CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cloud-services, azure-hdinsight

How does user specify the head/worker node instance type from CLI? I looked at the following links,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-create-cluster-cli

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-azure-cli

The link specifies worker count but does not mention about type of worker.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can choose the VM types in Azure CLI but you can try and validate using Powershell or ARM template

**ARM template**

1. Download the ARM template after the validation is passed

[image]

2. Add the below after modifying the VM type  next to the highlighted arrow
   [image]

**Powershell**
Please refer to this link-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-azure-powershell

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-supported-node-configuration#all-supported-regions-except-brazil-south-and-japan-west
and add

```
--workernode-size <>
--headnode-size <>
```